# How do you use replicas with network_mode in Docker?

Tags: docker

I am using [gluetun](https://github.com/qdm12/gluetun) with [invidious](https://invidious.io/), which allows me to proxy YouTube traffic through whatever I want.  However, when dealing with high request numbers on a public instance, the official way to increase Invidious's availability is by using replicas.  The docker-compose file for Invidious looks like this.

```
  invidious:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    deploy:
      replicas: 8
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: "service:gluetun"
    #ports:
    #  - "127.0.0.1:3000:3000"
```

The problem is, when replicas are started, they all try to bind to the gluetun's network on the same port.

```
invidious-invidious-4     |   from /usr/share/crystal/src/socket/addrinfo.cr:74:17 in 'initialize:reuse_port'
invidious-invidious-4     |   from /usr/share/crystal/src/socket/tcp_server.cr:36:3 in 'new:reuse_port'
invidious-invidious-4     |   from /usr/share/crystal/src/http/server.cr:213:18 in 'bind_tcp'
invidious-invidious-4     |   from lib/kemal/src/kemal.cr:52:7 in 'run'
invidious-invidious-4     |   from lib/kemal/src/kemal.cr:16:5 in 'run'
invidious-invidious-4     |   from lib/kemal/src/kemal.cr:15:3 in 'run'
invidious-invidious-4     |   from src/invidious.cr:238:1 in '__crystal_main'
invidious-invidious-4     |   from /usr/share/crystal/src/crystal/main.cr:115:5 in 'main_user_code'
invidious-invidious-4     |   from /usr/share/crystal/src/crystal/main.cr:101:7 in 'main'
invidious-invidious-4     |   from /usr/share/crystal/src/crystal/main.cr:127:3 in 'main'
invidious-invidious-4     |   from src/env/__libc_start_main.c:95:2 in 'libc_start_main_stage2'
```

Is there some way around this to get them to to play nice while using gluetun's network? This does not happen when not using gluetun, so I'm assuming the network_mode is the issue.

---

Port ranges do not work with network mode either, i.e.

```
  invidious:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 8
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: "service:pia"
    ports:
      - "3000-3008:3000"
```

```
Error response from daemon: conflicting options: port publishing and the container type network mode
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some way around this to get them to to play nice while using gluetun's network?

Only one process can bind to a given port in a particular namespace.

Rather than trying to connect all the invidious containers to gluetun's network, I would let them all run in their own network namespace and then run a round-robin proxy that is both connected to gluetun's network *and* to the network on which the invidious replicas are deployed. So the request flow would look like:

```
                                    +--> invidious0
                                    |
                                    +--> invidious1
                                    |
request +-->  gluetun +--> proxy +-----> invidious2
                                    |
                                    +--> invidious3
                                    |
                                    +--> invidious4
```

The proxy container would be connected to two networks -- the vpn network and the invidious network. The gluetun contained would only be connected to the vpn network, and the invidious replicas would only be connected to the invidious network.

A container-optimized proxy like [traefik](https://traefik.io/traefik/) is a good choice for this sort of thing, but you can also use more traditional proxies like nginx.

Here's an example compose file that demonstates this. It's based on the [stock invidious compose file](https://github.com/iv-org/invidious/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) (and assumes you have the `config` and `docker` directories from that repository), but adds multiple networks and the front-end proxy. This doesn't have a vpn container in it; you would add that connected to the `vpn` network. Note that the `traefik` container is listening for http requests on port 80.

```
networks:
  vpn:
  invidious:

services:
  proxy:
    image: docker.io/traefik:latest
    networks:
      - vpn
      - invidious
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3000:80"
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

  invidious:
    image: quay.io/invidious/invidious:latest
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.invidious.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.invidious.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)
    networks:
      - invidious
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      INVIDIOUS_CONFIG: |
        db:
          dbname: invidious
          user: kemal
          password: kemal
          host: invidious-db
          port: 5432
        check_tables: true
        # external_port:
        # domain:
        # https_only: false
        # statistics_enabled: false
        hmac_key: "LigCedbyettoicInArfugnowOcyenelyoyhulEj$"
    healthcheck:
      test: wget -nv --tries=1 --spider http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/comments/jNQXAC9IVRw || exit 1
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 2
    depends_on:
      invidious-db:
        condition: service_healthy

  invidious-db:
    image: docker.io/library/postgres:14
    networks:
      - invidious
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./config/sql:/config/sql
      - ./docker/init-invidious-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-invidious-db.sh
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: invidious
      POSTGRES_USER: kemal
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: kemal
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U $$POSTGRES_USER -d $$POSTGRES_DB"]

volumes:
  postgresdata:
```

Using this, try something like:

```
docker compose up --scale invidious=4
```

Then try repeatedly fetching http://localhost:3000/ on your host, and you should see each request being serviced by a different replica.